# Graded algebra and Hilbert–Poincaré series, closed formula, need some more detail.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra

In a now deleted question on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250364/graded-algebra-and-hilbert-poincar%C3%A9-series-reference-request-for-closed-formula), I asked the following question.

> Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra equipped with a grading $A = \oplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}A_i$, as a $k$-vector space.
>
> **Question.** Where can I find a reference to derivations of closed formulas for the formal power series$$P(A, t) := \sum_{i = 0}^\infty (\dim_k A_i) \cdot t^i$$in the cases where:
>
> 1. $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$,
> 2. $A = k\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle$,
>
> and $n \ge 1$? Or would anybody be so kind as to supply a quick derivation themselves?

Qiaochu Yuan gave the following answer in the comments.

> These are straightforward combinatorics exercises.
>
> 1. Poincaré series are multiplicative under tensor product, so the problem reduces to the case $n = 1$, where the Poincaré series is ${1\over{1 - t}}$. So in general it's ${1\over{(1 - t)^n}}$.
> 2. The number of words on $n$ letters of length $k$ is $n^k$, so the answer is ${1\over{1 - nt}}$.

The question was put on hold, presumably because it was at too low of a level for MathOverflow. However, I don't quite understand Qiaochu's answer, is it possible someone could add a bit more detail as to how he got his answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be sure you understand that $P(A\otimes B,t)=P(A,t)P(B,t)$. Now,
$$K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=K[x_1]\otimes K[x_2]\otimes\cdots\otimes K[x_n]$$
so the first problem reduces to computing $P(K[x],t)$. Well, the $k$th degree component of $K[x]$ is one-dimensional, spanned by $x^k$, so
$$P(K[x],t)=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-t}.$$
It follows that $P(K[x_1,\ldots,x_n],t)=\frac{1}{(1-t)^n}$.

As for the free algebra $K\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$, as Qiaochu noted, the number of words of length $k$ is $n^k$. As these words are linearly independent, the dimension of the $k$th degree component is $n^k$. So,
$$P(K\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle,t)=1+nt+n^2t^2+n^3t^3+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-nt}.$$

Comment: Actually one doesn't need tensor products to prove the first formula: combinatorics ("star and bars") or induction on $n$ do the job.