# The dimension of the graded algebra of a commutative ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, graded-algebras

Here is the question I am trying to understand it is solution:

(Poincare series of a graded algebra) Let $A = \bigoplus_{i \geq 1}A_i$ be a graded algebra such that the vector spaces $A_i$ are all finite-dimensional. Define the Poincare series of $A$ as the formal series $$P(A) = \sum_{i \geq 0} \operatorname{dim}(A_i)t^i.$$

Prove that $$P(k\{x_1, \dots , x_n \}) = \frac{1}{1 - nt} \text{  and  } P(k [x_1, \dots , x_n ]) = \frac{1}{(1 - t)^n}$$

[Graded algebra and Hilbert–Poincaré series, closed formula, need some more detail.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935824/graded-algebra-and-hilbert-poincar%c3%a9-series-closed-formula-need-some-more-detai)

I am almost ok with the proof of the first part **(the only thing that confuses me is why $|nt|<1$ ) any help will be appreciated in this case**) but I do not see the dimension of The dimension of the commutative graded algebra $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: About $|nt|<1$ I answered [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4626607/386889).

Comment: If you have further questions about a previous post, please try to ask for clarification there instead of posting a duplicate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The dimension of the commutative graded algebra" $A=k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is $\infty.$

The dimension of its component $A_i$ of degree $i$ [was not needed to compute $P_A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935824).

However, its computation is classical as well: since [it is the number of $n$-tuples $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of integers $e_j\ge0$ such that $\sum e_j=i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4626495/386889),
[$$\dim A_i=\binom{n+i-1}i.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)